# Search SQL Question Between Related Two Tables

Tags: php, sql, mysql, database

I am writing some kind of search engine for my web application and i have a problem. I have 2 tables first of is projects table:

**PROJECTS TABLE**

```
id                  int(11)         NO      PRI     NULL    auto_increment
employer_id         int(11)         NO      MUL     NULL     
project_title       varchar(100)    NO      MUL     NULL     
project_description text            NO              NULL     
project_budget      int(11)         NO              NULL     
project_allowedtime int(11)         NO              NULL     
project_deadline    datetime        NO              NULL     
total_bids          int(11)         NO              NULL     
average_bid         int(11)         NO              NULL     
created             datetime        NO      MUL     NULL     
active              tinyint(1)      NO      MUL     NULL
```

**PROJECTS_SKILLS TABLE**

```
project_id          int(11)         NO      MUL     NULL     
skill_id            int(11)         NO      MUL     NULL
```

For example: I want ask this query to database:

```
1-) Skills are 5 and 7.
2-) Order results by created
3-) project title contains "php" word.
4-) Returned rows should contain projects.* columuns.
5-) Projects should be distinct(i don't want same projects in return of query).
```

Please write sql query that ensure these conditions. Thank You.

Comment: One query for all conditions or just each query for each condition?

Comment: When you say skills are 5 and 7 - does that mean the results can have either, or must have both?

Comment: @vodkhang
For all conditions.

@OMG Ponies
5 Or 7

Comment: But you didn't try anything yet and want us to do something complex for you? It is not really complex but is it your homework or what sql did you try?

Comment: @vodkhang trying doesn't matter in this query because performance, proper query is very important for this web based application. And this is why i can't complate like homework !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT projects.*
FROM projects
WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM projects_skills
        WHERE skill_id = 5 
            AND project_id = projects.project_id
    )
    AND EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM projects_skills
        WHERE skill_id = 7
            AND project_id = projects.project_id
    )
    AND project_title LIKE '%php%'
ORDER BY created
```

or

```
SELECT projects.*
FROM projects
WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM projects_skills
        WHERE skill_id IN (5, 7) 
            AND project_id = projects.project_id
    )
    AND project_title LIKE '%php%'
ORDER BY created
```

Depending on what your intended result is.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you're looking for an `EXISTS` query, which verifies that matching rows exist in a table, but without performing a JOIN.

```
SELECT *
FROM projects
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM projects_skills AS ps WHERE ps.project_id = projects.project_id AND ps.skill_id IN (5, 7))
    AND project_title LIKE '%php%'
ORDER BY created;
```